# Tengo un problema con la instrucción msqli_fetch_array()

Tags: php

Este es el error que me sale:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Catalogo\catalogo.php on line 23

Y este es mi codigo

```
<?php 
    include_once './misc.inc.php';
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password, $basedeDatos);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno($conexion)) {
        echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }else{
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM Tipodemascota ORDER BY Tipodemascota";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
        echo '<div style="margin-left: .lin">
                <h1 align="center">Catalogo de mascotas</h1>
                <h2 align="center">Los siguientes animales amigos le esperan.</h2>
                <p align="center">Encuentre justo lo que desea y apresurese a venir a la tienda a recoger a su nuevo amigo.</p>
                <p><h3>¿En cual mascota esta interesado?</h3></p> <br>';
        echo '<form action="mostrar.php" method="POST">';
        echo '<table cellpadding="5" border="1">';
        $contador=1;
        while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
            extract($fila);
            echo '<tr><td valign="top" width="15%"><br>';
            echo '<input type="radio name="interes" value="$Tipomascota"';
            if($contador == 1){
                echo 'revisado';
            }
            echo '><font size="+1"><b>$Tipomascota</b></font>';
            echo '</td><td>Descripciontipo</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            $contador++;
        }
        echo '</table>';
        echo '<p><input type="submit" value="Elija un tipo de mascota"></form><br>';
    }   
    ?>
```

Comment: Prueba a usar **mysql_fetch_array** Sin la "i" en mysql.
Aun asi lo que te está diciendo el error es que la expresión esperaba
un tipo de dato **mysqli_result** y le has pasado un booleano.

Comment: El error parece indicar que esta consulta: `SELECT * FROM Tipodemascota ORDER BY Tipodemascota` no arroja ningún dato. ¿La has probado directamente en el manejador de Base de datos? ¿Funciona allí?  Por otra parte, no le veo demasiada lógica a tu código. Intentas leer los resultados aquí: `while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){` y luego haces un `extract($fila);` que no entiendo para qué ni lo que quieres hacer con los resultados obtenidos. En cualquier caso, siempre que consultes es bueno verificar si hay datos antes de intentar operar suponiendo que **siempre** los habrá.

Comment: Ese fallo ocurre cuando hay un error en la consulta. Por ejemplo, el SELECT que haces está leyendo de la tabla Tipodemascota e intenta hacer un ORDER BY por Tipodemascota... que es el nombre de la tabla, por lo que dará un error de sintaxis.